# Rails 2 - partials: what does @comment = Comment.new mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through a tutorial with the following code:

```
<h3>New Comment</h3>
   <%= render :partial => @comment = Comment.new,
   :locals => { :button_name => "Create" } %>
```

I believe that 'render :partial => @comment' works like 'render :partial => "comment", :object => @comment'

Where does ' = Comment.new' fit in?
Is it shorthand for :object?

Alan

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby terms,

```
@obj = Object.new # returns @obj
```

So you're rendering a comment partial and creating a new comment object that it can work with at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find any reference to this format via Google

Answer (score 3):

See http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Partials section "Rendering objects with the RecordIdentifier":

```
# <%= render :partial => "accounts/account", :locals => { :account => @buyer } %>
<%= render :partial => @account %>
```

Though documented, this is hardly used. The new+assignation (as explained by aharon) works, but it seems a bit tricky. In a tutorial you would expect to find a more orthodox approach:

- Create objects in controllers not in views.
- Use render :partial => 'mypartial', :locals => {...}

Comment: Thanks for the reference to apidock.com, it looks a very useful resource - Alan

Comment: I prefer the more verbose version myself too.